# MySQL wont start - Database crashed and now I get Error 1067

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-7

We have a MySQL database and last night there was a power outage which caused the machine it runs under to crash.

Now with the machine restarted, I am trying to run the MySQL service and I get the error:

"Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly"

Extract from the log:

```
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2015-12-14 08:56:17 d64 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 38.0M
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 33664440039 and 33664440039 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 35948349561 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-12-14 08:56:17 1248 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-12-14 08:56:24 1248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace teamcity/action_history which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\teamcity\action_history.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\teamcity\action_history.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as the message indicates, is likely to be performing innodb_force_recovery > 0.

To do this, just edit my.cnf, search the file for `innodb_force_recovery`, it'll look like this:

`#innodb_force_recovery = 0`

Edit it thusly:

`innodb_force_recovery = 2`

Then restart the MySQL service.  After stopping and restarting it, go back and replace the `#` in the my.cnf file, then restart the service again.  Hopefully, you are able to access your tables.  If not, try repeating the process, only set the value to 3 instead.  Do not go higher than 3 without further researching innodb_force_recovery.

Best of luck, hope this helps.